# how to write func about comparing boolean in func swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

Write a function that returns true if the student has a higher average grade than another student given as a parameter.

here my code

```
class Student {  

var id: Int = 0
var firstName: String = ""
var lastName: String = "" 

init(id: Int,firstName: String,lastName: String){
    self.id = id
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName

    }

func fullName() -> String  {

    return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }

var grades: [Float] = []

func addGrade(_ input: Float)    {
    grades.append(input)


}
func numberOfGrades() -> Int {
    return grades.count
}
func average(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    assert(grades.count > 0)
    return Float(grades.reduce(0, {$0 + Double($1)})/Double(grades.count))
}

func hasHigherAverageThan() -> Bool {
    if  lois.hasHigherAverageThan(peter){
    print("\(lois.firstName) beats \(peter.firstName)")
    }                        
} 
}
let peter = Student(id: 5, firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Parker")
peter.addGrade(2.95)
peter.addGrade(3.45) 
let lois = Student(id: 6, firstName: "Lois", lastName: "Lane")
lois.addGrade(4.0)
lois.addGrade(3.2)
```

How to write code correctly

i want output:Prints "Lois beats Peter"

Comment: This sounds like a classroom assignment. Are you allowed to get help with a classroom assignment without breaking your school's rules?

Comment: Yes it my practice for exams

Answer (score 0):

If your only method of comparison is the student's grades, consider the following:

```
func hasHigherGradeThan(_ student: Student) -> Bool {
     //In your current construct, the parameter passed to "average" is not necessary, so I'm passing a 0 right now.
     return self.average(numbers: 0) > student.average(numbers: 0)
}
```

This will only return true if one average is greater than the other; if the average is equal or lesser, it will return false.

Comment: I thought it would be better if the OP worked out the body of the method themselves. Giving students copy-and-paste-ready code means they don't learn how to solve problems themselves.

Comment: @Duncan-C, I get what you're saying. That being said, I'm a firm believer in answering questions where able. People learn in different ways; I believe the more exposure people have to different approaches of coding, the better they will become.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like you are supposed to write a an instance method of your `Student` class that takes another `Student` as a parameter and compares the two:

The function that compares 2 `Student` objects' average grades should not have any code dealing with specific students. It should be written as an instance method to compare the current student to another student.

```
class Student {
   //Your other code here...

   func hasHigherAverageThan(otherStudent: Student) -> Bool {
     //Your code to compare the current student to otherStudent goes here
     //comare `self` to `otherStudent` and return a Bool result
   }
}
```

Then, outside of the Student class, you would create and compare the 2 students:

```
let peter = Student(id: 5, firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Parker")
peter.addGrade(2.95)
peter.addGrade(3.45) 
let lois = Student(id: 6, firstName: "Lois", lastName: "Lane")
lois.addGrade(4.0)
lois.addGrade(3.2)      

if  lois.hasHigherAverageThan(peter) {
    print("\(lois.firstName) beats \(peter.firstName)")
} else {
    print("\(peter.firstName) beats \(lois.firstName)")
}
```

(Note that the code above does not allow for the 2 students having exactly the same average grade.)

See if you can work out the code for the `hasHigherAverageThan(otherStudent:)` method.

### EDIT:

One other thing: You gave your `Student` object an array of grade values, which seems reasonable. Why does your average function take any parameters, much less a variadic parameter? It should probably be written with no parameters:

```
func average() -> Float
```

It would use array `grades` to calculate the average grade.

### EDIT #2:

I would rewrite your average function like this:

```
func average() -> Float {
    guard !grades.isEmpty else { return 0.0 } 
    return Float(grades.reduce(0.0, { $0 + Double($1) })/Double(grades.count))
}
```

Changes:

1. Got rid of parameters
2. Got rid of assert and instead return 0 if array is empty

(You could also make it return an `Optional` `Float`/`Double`, and return nil if the array is empty.)

I would also suggest settling on one floating point type and using it throughout. Double is the native floating-point type, so I would make the array of grades an array of Doubles, and make the `average()` function return a `Double`.